# Sort an ArrayList based on Priorities obtained from a Map (Java version < Java8)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

What would be the best way to sort an ArrayList that has Strings according to the priorities obtained from a map.

For eg:
I have a Map with priorities assigned for specific use case (Key: pattern that I am looking for in the String and Value: Priority for that pattern)

```
Map pMap= new HashMap();
pMap.put("", 1);
pMap.put("1", 2);
pMap.put("2", 3);
pMap.put("3", 4);
pMap.put("4", 5);
pMap.put("*", 6);

List<String> listToBeSorted= new ArrayList<>();
listToBeSorted.add("Axxxx");
listToBeSorted.add("Ax4xx");
listToBeSorted.add("px*xxx");
listToBeSorted.add("px1xx");
```

I want to assign priority for each string in the list based on 3rd character, sort the list based on the priorities obtained.

My Approach :

Take the listToBeSorted, iterate over that and get the priority for each string and insert into a Temp Hashmap with the key being the String and value being its Priority.
Finally return the new Arraylist with sorted keys.

Result expected:
Arraylist that contains following data:

```
Axxxx
px1xx
Ax4xx
px*xxx
```

This approach works for now but I don't think this is a good approach when there is high volume of data.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

PS: I know there is a better solution in Java 8. But unfortunately I am unable to use it.So it would be great if someone could give me a better solution which is not in Java8?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Why not simply write a custom Comparator which takes the priority you're after, then use Collections.sort to sort the list, each time the compareTo method is called, you'd extract the value from the values and make a comparison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need a comparator that compares two strings based on their priorities:

```
Comparator<String> priorityBasedComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int priority1 = pMap.get(s1.substring(2, 3));
        int priority2 = pMap.get(s2.substring(2, 3));
        return Integer.compare(priority1, priority2);
    }
}
Collections.sort(list, priorityBasedComparator);
```

Of course, `pMap` should be declared as a `Map<String, Integer>` and not as a raw Map (you should never use raw types). And it should be `final` to be usable from the comparator.

Comment: That's what it does: pMap is the map, and pMap.get() returns a priority from the map. Do I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, may bad, just got into the substring and missed the rest :P - I took it as the op would provide a single value from the map, not use the map to look up the priority for each value, but this makes more sense

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. :)